# How to load vue component after being imported. May not load itself, should load in the file it's imported in

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to make a dynamic table with filters.
The filters are in `Filters.vue` and are supposed to be loaded in the `Table.vue`.
But the `Filters.vue` is not allowed to load itself, i want it to import itself into the `Table.vue` and then load `Table.vue` with the imported data from `Filters.vue`.

If `Filters.vue` loads itself then it will crash, i can fix the crash by putting the things in the prop in `Table.vue` html tag but that's not the way i want it to be.

---

Table.vue

```
 <div class="row m-3">
     <guide-filter></guide-filter>
 </div>
```

Filters.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <small class="text-cap mb-2 support-text-body">Status</small>
        <div class="w-100">
            <select v-model="filterResult.active" class="select2-selection custom-select">
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="1" >Active</option>
                <option value="false" >Archived</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <small class="text-cap mb-2 support-text-body">Language </small>
        <div class="w-100">
            <select v-model="filterResult.language_id" class="select2-selection custom-select">
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option v-for="language in languages" v-bind:key="language.id" v-bind:value="language.id">{{ language.name }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                filterResult: {},
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="col-sm-auto">
    <small class="text-cap mb-2 support-text-body">Language </small>
    <div class="w-100">
        <select v-model="filterResult.language_id" class="select2-selection custom-select">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option v-for="language in languages" v-bind:key="language.id" v-bind:value="language.id">{{ language.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see no difference?